# "Share" a sqlite table with another smartphone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, data-sharing

Maybe I'm going to ask a stupid question, but I can't find anything on the internet about this (explained in a simple way).

Here is the issue: I've got an app, in which the user organize data in SQLite Tables (you create a table so you can insert data in it). I would like to know if it's possible for me to send a table that I have previously created to another smartphone with the same app installed. 
I've no experience of these kinds of issues, so if anybody knows where to find a simple tutorial or has a hint... I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: this is the problem with sqlite... use firebase

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve it:

Sqlite is stored in a file in the device file system, Usually at: `//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>`
So assuming this is your application you can:

1. read the content of the DB into *List of objects* (List of rows for each table) and then to send this data over the internet.
2. Just send the sqlite file to the device and read it's content.

There are a lot of ways to do it. The simplest one is through a server - Upload the data to the server and notify the recipient that he has data to fetch from the server (Using FCM for example)

Comment: About the first way (point 1)... Is there any tutorial? Because I'm not an expert and I don't know how to start with the code. Anyway... thank you so much, you were very helpful